# WooCommerce - Stop all payments and pause system

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Is there any way - logically or through brute force - to stop WooCommerce from charging subscription members on my WordPress site?

I just went through an arduous process of migrating all my PayPal and Stripe users from WooCommerce to a custom system. From what I know, WooCommerce will charge subscriptions through triggers when someone accesses the webpage (instead of CRON jobs) - I'm not sure exactly how that works but its some PHP scheduler system.

Since I have migrated my customers, I no longer want WooCommerce to charge anyone - but the website is still live due to the long delay that DNS transfers take. That means that someone could access the site and trigger the WooCommerce subscription system.

Maybe I could implement something in htaccess where any request to the site would not route to WordPress/WooCommerce, but a "site has moved" page?